# Bochs Panicing After Not Finding Speaker In WSL

Tags: debugging, operating-system, low-level, bochs

I am making my own basic operating system and I obviously face some bugs, until now I have been just using the build logs but as the OS gets more complex it becomes very hard to debug. That's why I have started using Bochs to debug my OS but the problem I'm facing now is that Bochs is panicking every time. I have concluded that the reason for these panics is Bochs attempting to use the speakers, this results in a panic because I use WSL to develop the OS and as if right now WSL doesn't support audio so Bochs can't find any speakers.

I have tried using PulseAudio to counter that but I couldn't find and good tutorials. If anyone can help me set up PulseAudio or disable Bochs using speakers completely, that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in bochs config

```
plugin_ctrl: speaker=0
```

It worked for me in WSL2

Mentioned here https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html
4.3.1. plugin_ctrl